# htaccess conditional redirect to https

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So i'm trying to redirect to https all visitors except my internal networks 192.168.x and 10.x

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=(192\.168\.$|10\.$)
RewriteRule (.*) https:/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and something is wrong here since isn't working, connecting from internal network it still redirect me to https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RewriteCond Regex was the culprit. You should change it to

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(192\.168|10\.)
```

Click [here](http://regex101.com/r/wU0zT7/1) short Explanation how my regex works and click [here](http://regex101.com/r/oY4zL3/1) how your regex works

---

#### Long explanation:

The dot character `.` has special meaning in regex. It will match all character except new line. So, `192#168#` will match your regex `(192.168.$|10.$)`. If you want to match dot character, escape it with `\` character. Also you don't want to add dollar char `$` because it will assume mark the end of the line.